# Carregar parte da página em AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Estou a fazer uma aplicação.
A aplicação tem um topo, um menu lateral e o conteúdo de acordo com o menu seleccionado.

No conteúdo o utilizador poderá adicionar, remover, alterar e a minha dúvida é:
por exemplo, na hora de adicionar um novo registo devo fazer a actualização do conteúdo via AJAX, uma vez que todo o resto irá permanecer igual?

Penso que com AJAX a reposta é um pouco mais lenta, estou certo?
Nesse caso era melhor carregar normalmente?

Comment: @Miguel Angelo obrigado por editar mas estou em Portugal, aqui se diz registo e não registro.

Comment: Me desculpe! Vou retirar o 'r' então. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade a resposta via ajax é mais rápida, pois terá menos dados trafegando pela rede/internet.

Por exemplo, quando for excluir algo, pode fazer um AJAX para uma URL específica, e então retornar um JSON que contém apenas um valor verdadeiro ou falso, indicando se foi excluído ou não.

Isso é bem melhor que recarregar toda a página, e bem mais rápido... o único problema é que terá de fazer algumas manipulações via javascript.

Comment: Estou a utilizar jquery e não javascript puro, talvez seja por isso... o problema é que não posso retorna um true/false. Por exemplo, tenho uma lista com vários registos, edito um registo, gravo... tenho que "reconstruir" a lista e precisava montar todo o html.

Comment: O true/false foi um exemplo específico para exclusão. No caso da inserção/edição, poderia retornar um JSON com os dados editados e reconstruir usando o jquery, ou então retornar somente a parte da página que tiver de ser alterada e usar [`$.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) por exemplo, que é parte do jquery, e que permite substituir partes da página via AJAX.

Comment: OK, obrigado, vou utilizar AJAX nesses casos, já não me lembrava do $.load.

Comment: Precisando de orientação é só falar.